# visual studio 2015 rollback is not available

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2013 I had the option to rollback lines of code after I changed them. See picture rollback.

Now I switched to Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and this is not available anymore.

Is this something that is removed from Visual Studio 2015 or do I have to change some setting?

[image: rollback]

Answer (score 1):

That looks awfully much like the [Git Diff Margin extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LaurentKempe.GitDiffMargin):

[image]